# I have to write a very interesting query which calculates null values and rows with values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario where i need to calculate number of total values and number of null values against each ID
each ID column have a number of rows

Summarizing Data

```
- ID     Col1     Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
 - 132    12       0.5      0      Null     0.3     1.5
 - 132    Null     0.5      0      Null     0.3     1.5
 - 132    1        0.5      Null   Null     0.3     1.5
 - 132    2        0.5      0      0.3      1.5     Null  
 - 132    21       0.5      0      Null     0.3     1.5

 - 133    Null     Null     0      Null     Null    1.5
 - 133    12       0.5      0      Null     0.3     1.5
 - 133    Null     0.5      0      Null     0.3     1.5
 - 133    1        0.5      Null   Null     0.3     1.5
 - 133    2        0.5      0      0.3      1.5     Null  
 - 133    1        Null     0      Null     0.3     1.5
 - 133    Null     Null     0      Null     0.3     1.5
```

Summarizing Answer :I need to write a query which gives me the data like following

```
- ID      NullCount    ValuesCount
 - 132      7               21    
 - 133      15              27
```

I have a deployment quick help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How many columns in total? Only 6?

Comment: yes columns are fixed like 6 or more .... they remain same only number of rows can be different

Comment: Would the result for ID 132 not be 7 / 23?

Comment: yes it will be 7/23 my mistake

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: How to count null and non-null rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512691/oracle-how-to-count-null-and-non-null-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from [Oracle: How to count null and non-null rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512691/oracle-how-to-count-null-and-non-null-rows):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(Col1)+COUNT(Col2)+COUNT(Col3)+
  COUNT(Col4)+COUNT(Col5)+COUNT(Col6) AS ValuesCount,

  6*COUNT(*)-COUNT(Col1)-COUNT(Col2)-COUNT(Col3)-
  COUNT(Col4)-COUNT(Col5)-COUNT(Col6) AS NullCount
FROM data
GROUP BY id
```

`COUNT(ColX)` only counts `NOT NULL` values. Adding those for all six columns equals ValuesCount, of course.
`COUNT(*)` counts all rows, even if all columns within one row were `NULL`. Multiply by 6 for the total number of cells and then subtract all `NOT NULL` values to get the `NULL` count.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT` counts non-null values. So the `ValueCount` is easy - add the counts of each column.

For the `NullCount` you can use `CASE` or other similar logic. Or you can use `NVL2` function to turn anything NOT NULL into NULL and any NULL into something NOT NULL (like a constant.)

```
select id
     , count(nvl2(col1,null,1)) + count(nvl2(col2,null,1)) +
       count(nvl2(col3,null,1)) + count(nvl2(col4,null,1)) +
       count(nvl2(col5,null,1)) + count(nvl2(col6,null,1)) nullcount
     , count(col1) + count(col2) + count(col3) +
       count(col4) + count(col5) + count(col6) valuecount
  from tab
 group by id
 order by id
/
```

EDIT:

An alternative method is to *UNPIVOT* the data (which can be done using `UNPIVOT` or alternative unpivoting methods.)

```
select id
     , count(nvl2(col_value,null,1)) nullcount
     , count(col_value) valuecount
  from tab
 unpivot include nulls(
   col_value for col_name in (
      col1 as 'col1'
    , col2 as 'col2'
    , col3 as 'col3'
    , col4 as 'col4'
    , col5 as 'col5'
    , col6 as 'col6'
   )
 )
 group by id
 order by id
/
```

But when you have a fixed number of columns, it might be overkill to do unpivoting, when you can get the desired result in a single `GROUP BY` operation just by doing some copy-paste to specify all columns like my first example.

Answer (score 0):

-- The data

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2    SELECT 132 ID,  12  Col1,0.5  Col2,0  Col3,NULL Col4,0.3 Col5,1.5 Col6 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3    SELECT 132 ,   NULL ,    0.5  ,    0   ,   NULL  ,   0.3  ,   1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 132 ,   1   ,     0.5  ,    NULL,   NULL ,    0.3 ,   1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 132 ,   2  ,      0.5  ,    0 ,     0.3  ,    1.5 ,    NULL   FROM dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 132 ,   21 ,      0.5  ,    0  ,    NULL ,    0.3 ,    1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  7    SELECT 133 ,   NULL ,    NULL ,    0  ,    NULL ,    NULL ,   1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 133 ,   12  ,     0.5  ,    0  ,    NULL ,    0.3 ,    1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  9    SELECT 133 ,   NULL ,    0.5  ,    0  ,    NULL ,    0.3  ,   1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 133 ,   1  ,      0.5 ,     NULL,   NULL ,    0.3  ,   1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
 11    SELECT 133 ,   2  ,      0.5  ,    0  ,    0.3   ,   1.5 ,    NULL   FROM dual UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 133 ,   1  ,      NULL ,    0 ,     NULL  ,   0.3 ,    1.5 FROM dual UNION ALL
 13    SELECT 133 ,   NULL  ,   NULL ,    0 ,     NULL  ,   0.3  ,   1.5 FROM dual
 14    )
```

--The query

```
 15    SELECT ID, sum(cnt) as nullcount from(
 16    SELECT ID, count(*) cnt FROM DATA
 17    WHERE col1 IS NULL
 18    GROUP BY ID
 19    UNION ALL
 20    SELECT ID, count(*) FROM DATA
 21    WHERE col2 IS NULL
 22    GROUP BY ID
 23    UNION ALL
 24    SELECT ID, count(*) FROM DATA
 25    WHERE col3 IS NULL
 26    GROUP BY ID
 27    UNION ALL
 28    SELECT ID, count(*) FROM DATA
 29    WHERE col4 IS NULL
 30    GROUP BY ID
 31    UNION ALL
 32    SELECT ID, count(*) FROM DATA
 33    WHERE col5 IS NULL
 34    GROUP BY ID
 35    UNION ALL
 36    SELECT ID, count(*) FROM DATA
 37    WHERE col6 IS NULL
 38    GROUP BY ID
 39  )
 40  GROUP BY ID
 41  /

                  ID            NULLCOUNT
-------------------- --------------------
                 132                    7
                 133                   15

SQL>
```

Similarly for the `valuescount`, write an `in-line view`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 6 * cnt_all - cnt_not_null, cnt_not_null from (
  select id, count(*) cnt_all, 
             count(col1)+count(col2)+count(col3)+count(col4)+count(col5)+count(col6) cnt_not_null
  from tab group by id
);
```

6 is a number of columns

COUNT(col) doesn't take into consideration NULL values

COUNT(*) counts all values in a column including NULLS

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       (count(*) * 6) - (count(Col1) + count(Col2) + count(Col3) + count(Col4)+count(Col5)+count(Col6)) as NullCount, 
       count(Col1) + count(Col2) + count(Col3) + count(Col4)+count(Col5)+count(Col6) ValuesCount from 
       DATA 
group by id 
order by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

A horrible, but working version:

```
select distinct N.ID, 
(select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col1 is null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col2 is null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col3 is null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col4 is null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col5 is null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col6 is null) 'Null'
, 
(select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col1 is not null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col2 is not null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col3 is not null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col4 is not null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col5 is not null)
+ (select count(*) from tab N2 where N2.ID = N.ID and col6 is not null) 'Not null'
from tab N
```